# Help to write and read to/from serial

Tags: tty

I have bought a serial - USB adapter to connect my UPS (serial equipped) to my Raspberry machine and therefore to monitor the UPS.

The adapter is seen as /dev/USB1. The baud rate is 2400, the data lenght is 8 bit, stop bit 1 bit and no parity.

To get the status of the UPS, I should send to serial the command “Q1” followed by “cr” and then to read the output of the serial.

I have found following script:

```
tty=/dev/ttyUSB1

exec 4<$tty 5>$tty

stty -F $tty 9600 -echo

echo ‘Q1\n\r’ >&5

read reply <&4

echo "reply is $reply"
```

but it works just once and then it get stuck when executing the read command.

It looks like the serial get stuck after the first enquiry and then it returns alive after a few hours. Could it be?

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks, Daniele

Comment: Is this an exact replica of the command as copied from source, if so then this `‘` should have been `'`. That's one thing a see wrong with this script!

Comment: Just use `screen` or `byobu`. Don't bother with file descriptors. And add yourself to `dialout` group, since tty devices are owned by that group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like stated, `screen` would help.

`screen /dev/ttyUSB1 2400`

Note, you need to be in `dialout` group or issue connection from root account.

Comment: Thanks! I have never used screen. Can you please advise the purpose of using it to debug my script?

Comment: Just use screen to connect to ttyUSB, no need for script.

Comment: I solved it thanks to screen. Everything was correct but I did send ‘/r/n’ instead of ‘/r’ and it stuck the device. Thanks!